Wireguard DNS failure to resolve
It's always DNS...
I'm trying to set up a WireGuard server in an LXC container running on Proxmox. The VPN works in that all the local IP addresses are accessible but I can't get DNS working despite my best efforts.
Before and after connecting the VPN the result from:
nmcli dev show | grep 'IP4.DNS'
are
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.10.10
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.0.10.1
IP4.DNS[3]:                             1.1.1.1

and
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.10.10
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.0.10.1
IP4.DNS[3]:                             1.1.1.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.8.0.1

I have tried changing the client file to have either no DNS statement or to explicitly list a pi-hole instance on 10.0.10.10 or the main gateway 10.0.10.1 but still get an error.
When the VPN is connected I can dig and get correct results by using either of the following commands:
dig www.bbc.co.uk @10.0.10.10
dig www.bbc.co.uk @10.0.10.1

but I get a timeout if I simply run:
dig www.bbc.co.uk

The proxmox node DNS is set to use 10.0.10.1, 10.0.10.10 and 8.8.8.8
The two configuration files are:
Notes:
The end point (external) port is 51821 but the container is set to 51820 and the router uses NAT to forward correctly.
Server wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = server-private-key
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
# my laptop
PublicKey = client-public-key
PresharedKey = my-long-psk
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.4/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25

Client /etc/wireguard/home_lxc.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.4
PrivateKey = client-private-key
#DNS = 10.8.0.1  # These are the various option I have tried
#DNS=10.0.10.10
#DNS=10.0.10.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = server-public-key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PresharedKey = my-long-psk
Endpoint = wg.example.com:51821
PersistentKeepAlive = 25

Other info: When connected to the VPN a dig gives:
dig www.bbc.co.uk 
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> www.bbc.co.uk
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached

cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search nook

Advice would be gratefully accepted.

Ultimately the results are found in /etc/resolv.conf. So for each attempted case, you should check what happens to the content of /etc/resolv.conf.

In both cases the file contents is the same, I've edited the case above to add the result

So there's an interaction with systemd's built-in DNS resolver. You'll have to figure out how to prevent it to be used, or to get it to follow the requested DNS changes. I don't know how to solve this (I don't use systemd's built-in DNS resolver).
